# Autolayout unable to satisfy constraints that do not appear to conflict

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have placed a custom `UIView` of 80x80 into a custom `UITableViewCell` with the following constraints.

[image]

The **Content View** of is 80 high, while the **Safe Area** & overall `UITableViewCell` is 80.5 high, presumably to account for the line between cells. Xcode does not complain during the build process. I am not setting any other hardcoded constraints elsewhere in the application.

Yet at runtime, these appears to conflict, despite seemingly not appearing incorrect:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283f60190 WindDirectionIndicator:0x104f32ac0.height == 80   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283f60230 V:[WindDirectionIndicator:0x104f32ac0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x104f326d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283f60280 V:|-(0)-[WindDirectionIndicator:0x104f32ac0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x104f326d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283f60550 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x104f326d0.height == 80   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283f60190 WindDirectionIndicator:0x104f32ac0.height == 80   (active)>
```

It seems to agree that the bounds are placed at the top and bottom, and both the cell & UIView are 80 high. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you need the `bottom` constraint on the Wind Direction Indicator? I think if you have an explicit `height` and `width` Constraint and an X (`leading`),Y (`top`) Constraint that could be enough for AutoLayout to know where to render your view.

Comment: @Aaron removing the `bottom` constraint removes these errors, but causes the cells to collapse and Xcode to issue a warning of `Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.`

Comment: Try keeping the `bottom` constraint but lower the priority to 999. Does that fix it?

Comment: Yes it does! But why? Is this a hack or an actual solution?

Comment: Another possibility is that you are accidentally supplying a table view row height of 80. Your row height must be Automatic if you want the constraints to dictate the height.

Comment: Hmm, maybe accidentally? I'm certainly not intentionally doing so...